# Stuck in loop help - Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

The second 'if' statement midway through this code is using an 'or' between two conditions. This is causing the issue I just don't know how to get around it. The code is going through a data file and turning on the given relay number at a specific time, I need it to only do this once per given relay. If I use an 'and' between the conditions, it will only turn on the first relay that matches the current time and wait for the next hour and turn on the next given relay.

Could someone suggest something to fix this issue, thank you!

```
def schedule():
    metadata, sched = dbx.files_download(path=RELAYSCHEDULE)
    if not sched.content:
        pass  # If file is empty then exit routine
    else:
        relaySchedule = str(sched.content)
        commaNum = relaySchedule.count(',')
        data1 = relaySchedule.split(',')

        for i in range(commaNum):
            data2 = data1[i].split('-')
            Time1 = data2[1]
            currentRN = data2[0]
            currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
            currentHR = currentDT.hour
            global RN
            global T
            if str(currentHR) == str(Time1):
                if T != currentHR or RN != currentRN:
                    relaynum = int(data2[0])
                    relaytime = int(data2[2])
                    T = currentHR
                    RN = currentRN
                    k = threading.Thread(target=SendToRelay(relaynum, relaytime)).start()
            else:
                print("Pass")
```

**Desired Inputs:**

sched.content = '1-19-10,3-9-20,4-9-10,'

T = ' '

RN = ' '

T and RN are global variables because the loop is running indefinitely, they're there to let the loop know whether the specific Time(T) and Relay Number(RN) have already been used.

**Desired Outputs:**

If the time is 9 AM then,

T = 9

RN should be whatever the given relay number is so RN = 3, but not sure this is the right thing to use.

Sorry if this is confusing. I basically need the program to read a set of scheduled times for specific relays to turn on, I need it to read the current time and if it matches the time in the schedule it will then check which relay is within that time and turn it on for however long. Once it has completed that, I need it to go over that same set of data in case there is another relay within the same time that also needs to turn on, the issue is that if I don't use T and RN variables to check whether a previous relay has been set, it will read the file and turn on the same relay over and over.

Comment: Please edit to include a sample of your inputs and desired outputs/behavior.

Comment: What is `data1`? What are `RN` and `T`, and why are they `global`? Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. For anyone wondering this is the new working code:

```
def schedule():
metadata, sched = dbx.files_download(path=RELAYSCHEDULE)
if not sched.content:
    pass  # If file is empty then exit routine
else:
    relaySchedule = str(sched.content)
    commaNum = relaySchedule.count(',')
    data1 = relaySchedule.split(',')

    for i in range(commaNum):
        data2 = data1[i].split('-')
        TimeSched = data2[1]
        relaySched = data2[0]
        currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
        currentHR = currentDT.hour
        global RN
        global T
        if str(currentHR) == str(TimeSched):
            if str(T) != str(currentHR):
                RN = ''
                T = currentHR

            if str(relaySched) not in str(RN):
                relaynum = int(data2[0])
                relaytime = int(data2[2])
                k = threading.Thread(target=SendToRelay(relaynum, relaytime)).start()
                RN = str(RN) + str(relaySched)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing all used variables, check if everything is, what you think it is. On top of that, sometimes whietespaces characters causes problem with comparison.